# Error: Cannot find module '.models/Product'

Tags: nodejs

estoy intentando iniciar un script en Node.js pero me sale el siguiente error:

**Error: Cannot find module '.models/Product'
Require stack:

- C:\Users\emily\OneDrive\Escritorio\BOOTCAMP PROGRAMACION\Backend con Node\practica-node-js-mongo-db\nodepop\init-db.js
  at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1026:15)
  at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:872:27)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1092:19)    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
  at Object. (C:\Users\emily\OneDrive\Escritorio\BOOTCAMP PROGRAMACION\Backend con Node\practica-node-js-mongo-db\nodepop\init-db.js:3:17)
  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1205:14)
  at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1259:10)
  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1068:32)
  at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:909:12)
  at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:82:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',**

El codigo del script que intento inicializar es el siguiente:

```
const connection = require('./lib/connectMongoose')

const Product = require('.models/Product');

async function main() {
  await initProducts();
}

async function initProducts() {
  const result = await Product.deleteMany();
  console.log(result);
}

main().catch(err => console.log('Hubo un error', err))
```

He buscado por horas como resolver el error pero no encuentro solucion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un typo en la linea en la que requieres models/Product, pones .models/Product en vez de ./models/Product.

Por defecto, si pones un módulo sin referenciar a una ruta, node va a automaticamente buscarlo en node_modules. En tu caso, has puesto un `.` en vez de un `./` el cual es el que referencia a una ruta local

Comment: Muchas gracias no habia visto que me faltaba eso.... agradecida por la respuesta

Comment: Si quieres, marca la respuesta como correcta. Es un tick verde que sale y a mi me ayuda a obtener mas reputacion :D

Comment: listo, muchas gracias